# Why changing the UILabel text fires a viewDidLayoutSubviews event?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewdidlayoutsubviews

There are lots of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` events fired in my ViewController. Eventually I narrowed down to the single line of code which triggers the event:

```
self.debugLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", key, [@(tag) stringValue]];
```

Its a `UILabel` in a subview added to `self.view` of the ViewController. Why changing the text of a `UILabel` will cause boundary changes? In `viewDidLayoutSubviews` doc:

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view
>   adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this
>   method.

p.s. I am sure the debugLabel font size is small enough to fit in its frame.

Comment: I noticed this a while ago. It always just seemed like a bug to me.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the label's frame actually changes after setting its text?

Comment: There is no bug here. This is normal behavior. You are looking too closely and worrying about nothing. Don't worry, be happy. You shouldn't care how often layout is triggered.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is expected behavior and not a problem.

Comment: `setTitle:forState:` doesn't fire `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to do with auto-layout. If a view resizes then the constraints need to be checked throughout the rest of the view hierarchy to ensure that they are satisfied.

Comment: To put it more simply, a label's size constraints come by default from its _intrinsic size_ - which changes every time the label's contents change.

Comment: A completely clean project, without `Auto Layout`. Add a single `UILabel` to the view (in Storyboard) and you get a second `viewDidLayoutSubviews` call. Printing the root view and all its subview frames ( `viewDidLayoutSubviews`) shows non has changes on the second call. However, adding 5 more labels does not add any `viewDidLayoutSubviews` calls. Still unclear to me.